# Android app Force Closes on Database Connection attempt

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am trying to make a database connection with my app. It has an allow and deny button for a visitor. Whenever I try to call an operation of the database class my app force closes. For example, When I click on the Allow button I want the app to store the visitor id, date and string response in the database. 
Following is the code in the mainActivity that I have for the button:

```
//databaseVisitor VisDB = new databaseVisitor (this);
//VisitorDatabase VDB = new VisitorDatabase();
//Defining the actions of the Allow Button

Button.OnClickListener allowListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast allowToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toastYes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        allowToast.show();

        //Log.d("Insert Log: ", "Inserting add log..");
        //count = VisDB.getVisitorCount();
        response = "Access Granted";
        //dt = date.getDate();

        //VisDB.addVisitor(new VisitorDatabase(count+1, dt, response));

    }   
};
```

Comment: Post your LogCat errors so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Hi, @Marcin Czech first commented!

Comment: @Sam: These are the Logcat errors I am getting.
12-03 13:03:57.467: E/AndroidRuntime(283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 13:03:57.467: E/AndroidRuntime(283): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagefetch/com.example.imagefetch.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 13:03:57.467: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-03 13:03:57.467: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

Comment: Click "[edit]" to add your LogCat errors to your question so you can post all of them.

Comment: @Sam: Done. Thanks. I dont know why I didnt think of that.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.example.imagefetch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)` The error is on line 43, specifically in `onCreate()`. Post your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Line 43 is dt=date.getDate(); but if I convert that line to a comment line 59( is giving exception which VisDB.addVisitor(......);

Comment: I'm guessing that you forgot to initialize `date` with `date = ...` and you need to make `VisDB` a field variable (like `date`) to use in inside your OnClickListeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its most probably because you are closing the cursor

```
cursor.close()
```

and then making operations on it

```
return cursor.getCount()
```

try smthg like this

```
int count = cursor.getCount();
cursor.close();
return count;
```

EDIT :

and as for VisDB do it like that

```
...
databaseVisitor VisDB;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      VisDB = new databaseVisitor (this);
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now the count works although as soon as I try running any of the following two statements, it is still force closing.

    //dt = date.getDate();
     //VisDB.addVisitor(new VisitorDatabase(count+1, dt, response));
Any Idea why is that so? Thanks for your help. I used java.util.Date to get the getDate() method. and the variable dt is of type int. All variables have been declared in the main activity but not inside the OnCreate class because when I try doing so it gives an error saying "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method".

Comment: best would be to ask a new question and provide logcat stack to analyze. Did u try declaring variable as final?

Comment: I declared visdb as final. Are you referring to another variable?

Comment: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method" to what it refers to?

Comment: When I dont have final keyword attached to the databaseVisitor VisDB and when I refer to VisDB.getVisitorCount() from inside the onClickListener() or have count = VisDB.getVisitorCount();

Answer (score 1):

You closed the cursor before giving getCount ().
Try this:

```
int count = cursor.getCount();
cursor.close();
return count;
```

Good luck!